# row.names disappearing when using apply

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I have two matrices:

```
> x1
                a          c         c          d         e        f
2007-12 0.1988856 0.11641236 0.2807305 0.14357490 1.4118684 2.411518
2008-12 0.4176413 0.14818832 0.2296860 0.19274035 0.5882893 1.549960
2009-12 0.1838148 0.08337788 0.1525942 0.10716483 1.0585924 1.830152
2010-12 0.1234445 0.05693444 0.1056719 0.07402619 1.1792450 1.856027
2011-12 0.3646326 0.15624401 0.2733914 0.22585432 1.3659229 1.749772
2012-12 0.2238182 0.09063396 0.1523118 0.17185438 2.2483446 1.680515
2013-12 0.1845394 0.08367327 0.1530842 0.11662962 1.1007866 1.829547
> x2
                  a            c            c            d         e        f
2007-12 -0.01857119 -0.004988447 -0.006820523 -0.005919000 0.3110451 1.367264
2008-12  0.35842665  0.098544182  0.135910903  0.117976957 0.6160532 1.379187
2009-12 -0.04086404 -0.021609462 -0.045861809 -0.027875996 1.1854275 2.122302
2010-12  0.06818902  0.038316040  0.087461421  0.049706569 1.2126310 2.282632
2011-12  0.11147022  0.063797807  0.149175481  0.088120901 1.3743242 2.338254
2012-12  0.01204940  0.006597554  0.014581585  0.008174516 1.4905291 2.210150
2013-12 -0.15578076 -0.070454357 -0.128628802 -0.102376037 1.4801237 1.825704
```

Next I applying following function with following statements:

```
Fun <- function(x) unlist(lapply(list(all = x, nonnegatives = x[x >= 0.0], negatives = x[x < 0.0]), function(x) c(median = median(x))))

apply(x1, 2, Fun)
apply(x2, 2, Fun)
```

... and getting following results:

```
> apply(x1, 2, Fun)
                            a          c         c         d        e        f
all.median          0.1988856 0.09063396 0.1530842 0.1435749 1.179245 1.829547
nonnegatives.median 0.1988856 0.09063396 0.1530842 0.1435749 1.179245 1.829547
negatives.median.NA        NA         NA        NA        NA       NA       NA
> apply(x2, 2, Fun)
               a            c           c            d        e        f
[1,]  0.01204940  0.006597554  0.01458159  0.008174516 1.212631 2.122302
[2,]  0.08982962  0.051056923  0.11168616  0.068913735 1.212631 2.122302
[3,] -0.04086404 -0.021609462 -0.04586181 -0.027875996       NA       NA
```

As seen there, first matrix has row.names, but second matrix - not. Why this happens and how to avoid it?

Comment: I can't figure out what your desired output could look like: you have just 3 rows now, where do you want this row.names to appear?

Comment: Ops, sorry I didn't understand the question. You were comparing the two output matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could modify the function to get the output with rownames even in cases where some of the elements are NA while others are not NA.

```
Fun1 <- function(x) unlist(lapply(list(all = x, 
    nonnegatives = x[x >= 0.0], negatives = x[x < 0.0]),
    function(x) if(length(x)==0) c(median=NA) else c(median=median(x))))
```

For the first case, all the elements for the third row is 'NA'.

```
apply(x1, 2, Fun1)
#                            a          c       c.1         d        e        f
#all.median          0.1988856 0.09063396 0.1530842 0.1435749 1.179245 1.829547
#nonnegatives.median 0.1988856 0.09063396 0.1530842 0.1435749 1.179245 1.829547
#negatives.median           NA         NA        NA        NA       NA       NA
```

While in the second matrix, only some elements for the third row is NA.  Therefore some have name attributes and some doesn't.  When we unlist, the name attributes are lost.  But, modifying the function to include the 'name' attributes even in cases with NA will ensure the output to have the row names.

```
 apply(x2, 2, Fun1)
 #                      a            c         c.1            d        e
 #all.median          0.01204940  0.006597554  0.01458158  0.008174516 1.212631
 #nonnegatives.median 0.08982962  0.051056924  0.11168616  0.068913735 1.212631
 #negatives.median   -0.04086404 -0.021609462 -0.04586181 -0.027875996       NA
 #                         f
 #all.median          2.122302
 #nonnegatives.median 2.122302
 #negatives.median          NA
```

If 'x1' and 'x2' are 'data.frames', this could be done with `sapply/lapply`

```
Fun2 <- function(x) c(all.median=median(x), nonnegatives.median =
        median(x[x >=0.0]), negatives.median=median(x[x < 0.0]))

 sapply(x2, Fun2)
 #                     a            c         c.1            d        e
 #all.median         0.01204940  0.006597554  0.01458158  0.008174516 1.212631
 #nonnegatives.median 0.08982962  0.051056924  0.11168616  0.068913735 1.212631
 #negatives.median   -0.04086404 -0.021609462 -0.04586181 -0.027875996       NA
 #                         f
 #all.median          2.122302
 #nonnegatives.median 2.122302
 #negatives.median          NA
```